# Posicionar resposta de busca em inputs

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Estou fazendo uma busca em meu `BD` e tentando posicionar os resultado em alguns `inputs`, consigo efetuar a pesquisa e obter os dados que preciso, mas ao posicionar o resultado em meus `inputs` os mesmos estão ficando triplicados e não respeitando o posicionamento definido, estou usando um `grid` `bootstrap` para exibir o resultado, o que fiz foi isso:

Formulário que dispara a pesquisa e os campos onde estou posicionando o resultado:

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <label>Agrônomo - Técnico *</label>
    <select name="Tecnico" id="Tecnico" onchange="buscaDados()" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">Agrônomos - Técnicos</option>
      <?php foreach ($ResTecnico as $Tecnico) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $Tecnico->IdTecnico ?>"><?php echo $Tecnico->Nome ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

A função:

```
function buscaDados(){
  var Tecnico = $('#Tecnico').val();  
  if(Tecnico){
    var url = 'buscaDados.php?IdTecnico='+Tecnico 
    $.get(url, function(dataReturn) {
      $('#cpf').html(dataReturn);  
      $('#crea').html(dataReturn); 
      $('#renasem').html(dataReturn); 
    });
  }
```

A pesquisa no `BD`

```
require_once "../_classes/conexao_pdo.class.php";
require_once "../_classes/crud.class.php";

// Atribui uma conexão PDO   
$pdo = Conexao::getInstance();
// Atribui uma instância da classe Crud, passando como parâmetro a conexão PDO e o nome da tabela  
$crud = Crud::getInstance($pdo, 'ubsTecnico');

$IdTecnico = $_GET['IdTecnico'];  //codigo do estado passado por parametro

// CPF
$sqlTecnico = "SELECT * FROM  `ubsTecnico` WHERE ubsTecnico.IdTecnico = ?";
$arrayParam  = array($IdTecnico);
$ResDadosTecnico = $crud->getSQLGeneric($sqlTecnico, $arrayParam, TRUE);    


foreach ($ResDadosTecnico as $DadosTecnico) { ?>

CPF *
Cpf; ?>" class="form-control required">

CREA *
Crea; ?>" class="form-control required">

RENASEM *
Renasem; ?>" class="form-control required">
}
```

Onde as informações devem ficar:

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4" id="cpf">                    
    <!-- DADOS DO CPF !-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4" id="crea">
    <!-- DADOS DO CREA !-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4" id="renasem">
    <!-- DADOS DO RENASEM !-->                  
  </div>                  
</div>
```

A imagem de como está ficando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A questão é que você está retornando um `html` no seu `ajax` que já trás todos os dados de uma vez, e pra cada `.html()`, você imprime o mesmo, no caso, 3 vezes.

Você precisa escolher das duas uma:

**Retornar um resultado para cada e executar um `ajax` para cada `input`**

O que seria algo do tipo:

```
 //neste caso faria um ajax para cada campo, sendo field o id de qual dado esta a buscar
 function buscaDados(field){
    var Tecnico = $('#Tecnico').val();  
    if(Tecnico){
        var url = 'buscaDados.php?campo='+field+'&IdTecnico='+Tecnico 
        $.get(url, function(dataReturn) {
            $('#'+field).html(dataReturn);  
       });
    }
 }
```

**Ou, retornar o `html` completo a imprimir tudo em uma única `div`**

```
 function buscaDados(){
    var Tecnico = $('#Tecnico').val();  
    if(Tecnico){
        var url = 'buscaDados.php?IdTecnico='+Tecnico 
        $.get(url, function(dataReturn) {
            $('.form-group#fields').html(dataReturn);  
       });
    }
 }
```

E a sua `div`:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group" id="fields">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Caso tenha alguma dúvida ta um toque!

Comment: Obrigado @Kenny Rafael, sua dica foi fenomenal, resolveu meu problema.